# Can not retrieve variable of type System.Collections.Hashtable in powershell console

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, azure-powershell

I'm trying to retrieve a variable of type `hastable` from a PowerShell script execution.

explanation :

I execute te script using `./scriptName.ps1 -PAT *****`
As you can see, I created an environment variable `$env:Head` in the script in order to get an output of the `$header` variable.
The `$header` variable is of type `hastable` in the script, but when I display the `$env:Head` in the powershell console, it shows the string `System.Collections.Hashtable`

I would like to get the hashtable like :

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
authorization                  Basic ********
```

Do you know how to get the hashtable content instead of the this string content?

Thank you for any help.

```
param (
    [string]$PAT
)

$Personal_Access_Token = "$PAT"
$user = ""
$token = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user, $Personal_Access_Token)))
$header = @{authorization = "Basic $token"}
$env:Head = $header.psobject.ImmediateBaseObject
```

[image]

Comment: As an aside: Note that you do _not_ need `.psobject.ImmediateBaseObject`, which is in effect a no-op. `$env:Head = $header` would work the same (though wouldn't do what you want).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below:

Here is the changed script(updated your script):

```
param (
    [string]$PAT
)

$Personal_Access_Token = "$PAT"
$user = ""
$token = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user, $Personal_Access_Token)))
$header = @{authorization = "Basic $token"}
$global:Head = $header.psobject.ImmediateBaseObject
```

[image]

Used `$global` here. This will ensure global scope which will allow you to get values in Console.

Comment: I didn't know the key word `global`. Thank you so much for this help and for teaching me the global scope ! :)

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr**

- If you don't actually need an *environment* variable - which would be necessary for sharing your hashtable *across process boundaries* - see [RithwikBojja's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75695516/45375) for a solution based on a (global) *PowerShell* variable.
- If you *do* need an environment variable, you must decide on and create a - meaningful - *string* representation, given that environment variables can only store *strings*.

  - One option is to use *JSON*:

```bash
# $env:Head then contains the following *string*:
#  {
#    "authorization": "Basic <value-of-$token>"
#  }
$env:Head = @{authorization = "Basic $token"} | ConvertTo-Json
```

- If the consumer of this value (in a different process) is *also* PowerShell, it can recreate a hashtable from the environment variable with:

```bash
$env:Head | ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashtable
```

Read on for background information and alternatives.

---

###### Sharing complex values via environment variables:

- If using a ***PowerShell* variable** (seen only in the session at hand) rather than an *environment* variable (also inherited by *child processes*) is acceptable, you can indeed use `$global:Head` instead of `$env:Head`, as shown in RithwikBojja's answer.

  - Note: Global variables are seen *session*-global, which means that *any* subsequent code executing in the session sees them too, which may or may not be the intent. (While environment variables too are seen session-wide (process-wide), that is usually the intent, and accessing them requires deliberate use of the `$env:` variable namespace)
  - In the realm of PowerShell code, it is **usually better to communicate values between scripts / functions *via output* rather than via (global) variables**. E.g., you could have simply used `$header` as a statement (which is in effect short for `Write-Output $header`) in order to *output* the hashtable from your script.
- ***Environment* variables** are needed if you want to share the value *across process boundaries*. Environment variables **can each only store a *single string***, not complex objects such as [hashtables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables).

  - Therefore, assigning a complex object to an environment variable (`$env:Head =  @{authorization = "Basic $token"}` - note that you do *not* need `.psobject.ImmediateBaseObject`, which is in effect a no-op) results in *implicit stringification*
  - Unless a given complex object's type *happens to* implement a meaningful string representation by overriding its inherited [`.ToString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Object.ToString) method, any instance of that type will simply - and mostly uselessly - stringify as its *full type name*, which is what you saw with your [`[hashtable]` (`System.Collections.Hashtable`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Hashtable) instance:

    ```bash
    # -> 'System.Collections.Hashtable'
    @{authorization = "Basic $token"}.ToString()
    ```
  - In general, a *string* representation isn't guaranteed to be *faithful, reversible* representation of a complex object, but those composed only of well-known, primitive types can be:

    - You can **use a *structured text format*, such as JSON**, using [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json):

      ```bash
      $env:Head = @{authorization = "Basic $token"} | ConvertTo-Json
      ```

      - To later recreate a `[hashtable]` instance in PowerShell, you can use [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json):

        ```bash
         $env:Head | ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashtable
        ```
    - **Alternatively** can use PowerShell's own XML-based object-serialization format, **CLIXML**, via the [`[System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer) .NET API:

      ```bash
      $env:Head =
        [System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Serialize(
          @{authorization = "Basic $token"}
        )
      ```

      - To later recreate a `[hashtable]` instance in PowerShell:

        ```bash
        [System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Deserialize(
          $env:Head
        )
        ```
    - Finally, **if you only need a *for-display* representation** - which isn't suitable for *programmatic* processing - you can use [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string) (which you may precede by a call to a `Format-*` cmdlet such as [`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table) or [`Format-List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-list) to select a particular format):

      ```bash
      # Note: $env:Head's value will then *look like* a hashtable,
      #       but it's simply its for-display *string representation*.
      $env:Head = @{authorization = "Basic $token"} | Out-String
      ```